# tourist visa application for second wife to Canadian permanent resident

Tags: visas, legal, canada, tourist-visas

My friend is Canadian permanent resident and so is his wife and 2 sons. After they did the landing in Canada my friend got married to another wife when he  was working in  India and adopted her daughter. He is a Muslim and his religion allows a 2nd marriage.

This happened a few months back and without the knowledge of his 1st wife. Both his 2nd wife and his daughter are Indian Citizens and want to visit Canada for tourism purpose. Going through the application to check if they are eligible for such a visa there was a question "Do you have a Family member who is a Canadian Citizen or permanent resident and is 18 years or older?" and then some other questions somehow related to the same matter.

- In this case should the answer be YES (which means a husband for the 2nd wife  and a father for the daughter)?
- Will his 2nd wife and his daughter be eligible for getting a tourist visa and visit Canada?
- Or as they have a family member who is a permanent resident (husband to the 2nd wife and father of  the daughter) will this negatively impact their visa application and/or issuance?
- As they are coming for a tourist visit and not to live in Canada will they still be affected by saying the truth?
- Will answering YES in their application to the Visa create a problem for my friend and/or effect his current permanent resident status?

Comment: Kindly he needs a reliable answers and the matter is not for jok

Comment: Honestly, I think your friend needs a good immigration lawyer.

Comment: We cannot answer the last question about immigration; see [expatriates.se] for that question. For the rest, you should be aware that putting false information on the visa application is a good way to be refused and banned.

Comment: In many countries, second marriages are not recognized, so the second wife would have no preferential status based on the marriage.  I don't know whether this is the case in Canada, and I don't know whether that would also affect the status of the adopted daughter.

Comment: Polygamy is a [criminal offence](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/page-70.html?txthl=polygamy#s-293) in Canada

Comment: I have improved spelling and formatting and removed your last question as it is off-topic here. For the rest, I can agree with all the comments made so far.

Comment: Have not told first wife and committed a criminal offence in Canada, I think an immigration lawyer is not the only lawyer he needs.

Comment: @kiradotee: "and committed a criminal offence in Canada" Canadian criminal code generally only applies to acts performed in Canada. Otherwise any polygamist anywhere in the world would have committed a criminal offense in Canada.

Comment: "Both his 2nd wife and his daughter are Indian Citizens and want to visit Canada for tourism purpose". Call me cynical...

Comment: @user102008: It wouldn't seem outrageous to me if Canada considered the offense to happen in Canada just if the perpetrator lives or lived with one of the spouses in Canada. After all, that is where that spouse is _wronged_, believing that she has entered into an exclusive legal relation with the perp, and falsely relying on this. But actually [Canadian law doesn't do that](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/page-70.html) unless the bigamist is a Canadian citizen.

Comment: As the issue has already been raised in the Supreme Court, and the law upheld - and polygamous marriages are not recognized under the law, I don't see much hope for this person. As for the minor, she can be adopted using the normal process, and no special preference would be allowed as the marriage is simply not recognized in Canada.

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to dissent a bit from the general gist here since I'm not so sure this is all that complicated. If your friend had married both wives prior to coming to Canada CIC would only have recognized the first marriage and would treat the second spouse as if no relationship existed. The second wife would have no relative in Canada, the daughter might or might not have one depending on the basis for the adoption (if it depended on the marriage it might be considered nonexistent as well). Whether a visa application would be successful is a different issue, but if the second wife  behaved consistently with their view that any prior relationship did not survive the husband's move to Canada this might work out. There is an article [here](http://www.macleans.ca/politics/how-to-get-into-canada-if-youre-a-polygamist/) discussing this that includes a CIC memo on the topic.

Unfortunately this is apparently not what happened. Instead I understand what happened to be that your friend moved to Canada with his only wife at the time and then, after becoming a permanent resident, acquired the second wife. This is a clear violation of [Canada's bigamy law](http://yourlaws.ca/criminal-code-canada/290-bigamy), an indictable offense punishable by up to 5 years in prison. If Canada found evidence that your friend had done this then, whether the second wife visited Canada or not, this very well might jeopardize not only his immigrant status but his freedom.

When your friend moved to Canada he voluntarily subjected himself to Canadian law from that point forward. I don't know what it says about your friend that he ignored his obligation to observe those laws, but I suspect it would be in his best interest for his second wife to not have any interaction with a Canadian official who might, even accidentally, come to know the facts of what occurred.

Comment: @pnuts I think the provision was carefully written to avoid extra territorial law issues. It criminalizes leaving Canada "with intent to do anything mentioned in subparagraphs (a)(i) to (iii)" if the intention is carried out. Leaving Canada is an action that necessarily starts in Canada, and so is a proper subject for Canadian law.

Comment: @pnuts,  The only "extra territorial law" issue I see is that marriages entered into outside Canada are legally recognized as marriages inside Canada too. As this is the basis for much family immigration I don't see much wrong with that. The (very old) law that people residing in Canada have only one spouse applies only to people residing in Canada but, again, marriages entered into outside Canada are considered valid marriages. CIC (unlike USCIS) doesn't treat prior plural marriages as prejudicial, but the immigration benefit requires conformance with local law upon arrival.

Comment: dear all , my friend was not aware at all that such marriage is a violation. are we concluding here that he is in Violation to Canadian law and he is subjected to punishment?

Comment: @Saeed We are concluding that your friend needs to speak to an immigration lawyer for further advice.

Answer (score 7):

In short, this is a complicated legal issue. Your friend is married to two different people, without the knowledge of his first wife, and in potential violation of Canadian law which bans polygamy.

The questions here amount to a request for legal advice, and the complexity of the situation is well beyond what an internet forum can provide. Your friend needs a well-qualified lawyer to help answer these questions, and many other relevant ones; not merely an immigration consultant who can help prepare paperwork, but an attorney who is able to research the relevant law and advise on the risks and benefits of various courses of action.